# Is there a way to split time in intervals using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, timestamp

I am trying to split a dataframe in time intervals, given the time stamp of each row.  For example if the date is 12/20/18 02:20:00, I want to be able to create a new column and label this as 12am-6am. I am trying to use .loc() to create this column, but splitting the time is proving to be a challenge to me.  tried using between_time, changing my index to the time stamp, and I also used date_range as well as np.where().

```
df1.loc[df1['Date'].date_range("0:00", "6:00").time, 'interval'] = '12am-6am'
```

or even using the Date column:

```
df1['Date'].loc[df1['Date'].date_range("0:00", "6:00").time, 'interval'] = '12am-6am'
```

The np.where() seems to compile but it does not give me the correct classification:

```
df1['new'] = np.where(df1.Date.dt.hour > 0, '12-6','nothing')
```

For rows that satisfy the time, it labels as "nothing"

My overall goal is to use group_by() to group my data frame into this intervals, so if there is an easier and faster solution using the timestamp column, Id love to read it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `np.select`:

```
(np.select([df.Timestamp.dt.hour.ge(6) & df.Timestamp.dt.hour.le(12) & df[col].notnull(), df.Timestamp.dt.hour.ge(12) & df.Timestamp.dt.hour.le(18) & df[col].notnull()], ['M', 'A'], default='E'))
```

using `pd.cut`:

```
b = [6,12,18,24]
l = ['M', 'A','E']
pd.cut(df.Timestamp.dt.hour, bins=b, labels=l, include_lowest=True)
```

You can modify the code as per your need.